# How to get popup to animate?

Tags: c#, wpf

Here is my code (Say we have a single button on the page that initiates the popup):

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Width = 50;
        rect.Height = 50;

        Popup mypop = new Popup();
        mypop.Child = rect; // just to put something inside the popup for now           
        mypop.PopupAnimation = PopupAnimation.Slide;
        mypop.StaysOpen = false;
        mypop.PlacementTarget = button1; // open next to the button
        mypop.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

The popup just appears without animating, even though I set the PopupAnimation property.. anyone know why?

Comment: Perhaps it should be animated in a separate thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: [Popup class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.aspx):

> A Popup control supports animation when the AllowsTransparency property is set to true and the application is running with full trust

Comment: Yep, I needed to do mypop.AllowsTransparency = true, and give a solid color to my rectangle.